# R plotly customdata format variations

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, r-plotly, ggplotly

I am trying to access the `customdata` assigned to each data point via the javascrit (for instance to assign an hyperlink to each point). However, I noticed that the data format changes from one plot to the other, which seems bizarre.

This works perfectly in this example (based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71549382/how-to-make-tiles-open-a-hyperlink-using-ggplotly-r) post), that is when the `fill` aesthetic is a `character` vector:

```r
library(plotly)
library(htmlwidgets)

js <- "function(el, x) {
         el.on('plotly_click', function(d) {
           console.log(d);
           console.log(d.points[0].data.customdata[0]);
       });
       }"

X <- data.frame(x = c(1, 2, 1, 2), y = c(1, 1, 2, 2), z = as.character(1:4), mydata = letters[1:4])

gg <- ggplot(X, aes(x = x, y = y, customdata = mydata)) + geom_tile(aes(fill = z))

ggplotly(gg) %>% onRender(js)
```

[image]
As can be seen, a single and correct custom data shows up when clicking on each point. The structure of the customdata is similar to other plots.

However, when `z` is entered as a numerical variable, the structure of the customdata behaves bizarrely:

```r
X <- data.frame(x = c(1, 2, 1, 2), y = c(1, 1, 2, 2), z = 1:4, mydata = letters[1:4])

gg <- ggplot(X, aes(x = x, y = y, customdata = mydata)) + geom_tile(aes(fill = z))

ggplotly(gg) %>% onRender(js)
```

[image]
Is this a bug? How can I fix this? In fact, my dataset is much larger than the one in this example.

---

**Edit**
@ismirsehregal provided a solution that works for the above example. However, it seems that `customdata` takes the vector data *as is*, which seems quite wrong. Therefore, if we change the order of `X` the `js` script stop working.

Showcase:

```r
library(plotly)
library(htmlwidgets)

js <- "function(el, x) {
         el.on('plotly_click', function(d) {
           var zdimensions = [ 0, 0 ];
           var vecindex = 0;
           var clickedcustomdata = '';
           
           var zdimensions = [ d.points[0].data.z.length, d.points[0].data.z[0].length ];
           vecindex = d.points[0].pointIndex[0]*zdimensions[1] + d.points[0].pointIndex[1];
           clickedcustomdata = d.points[0].data.customdata[vecindex];
           console.log(d);
           console.log(clickedcustomdata);
         });
       }"

X <- data.frame(x = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3),
                y = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2), 
                z = 1:6,
                mydata = letters[1:6])

X <- X[order(-X$z),]

gg <- ggplot(X, aes(x = x, y = y, customdata = mydata)) + geom_tile(aes(fill = z))
fig <- ggplotly(gg) %>% onRender(js)
fig
```

[image]

I guess a potential solution would be to previously order `X` in R so it matches the matrix order?

Comment: It might be possible to find a workaround using the `pointIndex`. I'd also consider [filing an issue](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.R/issues).

Comment: @ismirsehregal Will file a issue. I am not sure how to build an index from `pointIndex`. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a workaround based on the `pointIndex`.

I'm calculating the vector index for `customdata` based on the provided `pointIndex`:

```
library(plotly)
library(htmlwidgets)

js <- "function(el, x) {
         el.on('plotly_click', function(d) {
           var zdimensions = [ 0, 0 ];
           var vecindex = 0;
           var clickedcustomdata = '';
           
           var zdimensions = [ d.points[0].data.z.length, d.points[0].data.z[0].length ];
           vecindex = d.points[0].pointIndex[0]*zdimensions[1] + d.points[0].pointIndex[1];
           clickedcustomdata = d.points[0].data.customdata[vecindex];
           console.log(clickedcustomdata);
         });
       }"

X <- data.frame(x = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2), y = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3), z = 1:6, mydata = letters[1:6])
gg <- ggplot(X, aes(x = x, y = y, customdata = mydata)) + geom_tile(aes(fill = z))
fig <- ggplotly(gg) %>% onRender(js)
fig
```

[image: result]

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11587049/9841389) was useful to get here.

Still I'd encourage you to file an issue on GitHub, so this is fixed officially.

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly! Filed an issue [here](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.R/issues/2120).

Comment: Could you please have a look at my edit? The script stops working as soon as we reorder the dataset.

Comment: @mat - yes you'll have to maintain the order of the `customdata` before passing it to plotly otherwise the array/vector mapping won't work.